# How to parameterize the limit in cts:uri in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10

`cts:uri-match("/pattern*.xml", ("limit= {$limit} ")` --> this throws an error

Is there a way to pass the limit value as variable(`$limit`)?

Answer (score 1):

Inside of a quoted string literal you can't start a code block.

Alternative solutions to achieve what you want:

You can use the [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-concat) function:

```
let $limit := 100
return
  cts:uri-match("/pattern*.xml", concat("limit=", $limit) )
```

You can concatenate with the `||` operator:

```
let $limit := 100
return
  cts:uri-match("/pattern*.xml", "limit="||$limit)
```